# My ListView is not visible in android emulator, I have used Linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

My problem is that list view is not visible on my android emulator
Below is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyListview">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
</LinearLayout>
```

below is my string.xml fie

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">MyListView</string>
<string-array name="myarray">
    <item value="Abc"></item>
    <item value="Def"></item>
    <item value="ghi"></item>
    <item value="jkl"></item>

</string-array>
```

Below is my.java file:

```
package com.example.mypc.mylistview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import  android.widget.*;

public class MyListview extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter ad;
String []arr={"abc","def","ghi","jkl"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_listview);

    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

       ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr);

    lv.setAdapter(ad);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          String []arr=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray);
            String value=arr[position];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}
}
```

Below is my output:

Here is the output after passing array inside array adapter

[image: Here is the output after passing array inside array adapter]

Is there anything wrong in my java file or I have taken wrong layout?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Simple use this in MainActivity.java


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView  listView=findViewById(R.id.listviewa);

        String [] value=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.radio_buttons);
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, value);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

//---------------------String.xml-

<resources>
    <string name="app_name">YourAppName</string>


    <string-array name="radio_buttons">
        <item>ABC</item>
        <item>DEF</item>
        <item>GHX</item>
        <item>IJK</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: if any problem facing regarding this please let me know.Thank you

Comment: @ Vishal sharma ,I  passed  android.R.id.text1 inside arrayAdapter ,Now my List is visible but the toast msg is not displayed ,it only shows the empty black box in place of showing toast msg ,By the way thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you can saw in the screenshot every thing is fine. List view is there but the color of the **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1** is white thats why its not showing. You can try

e.g. mytextview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:textColor="@color/font_content"
    android:padding="5sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rectgrad"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

And your java file is now:

```
package com.example.mypc.mylistview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import  android.widget.*;

public class MyListview extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter ad;
String []arr={"abc","def","ghi","jkl"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_listview);

    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

       ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.mytextview,arr);

    lv.setAdapter(ad);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          String []arr=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray);
            String value=arr[position];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}
}
```

And it definetly works.

Comment: it says"Unfortunately the application has been stopped" ,well thanks for suggesting

Comment: Try this 
**ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.mytextview,R.id.tv, arr);**